# Iron-session set cookie maxAge

Tags: javascript, session, next.js

I'm trying to set up a Next JS app with iron-session and a 'remember me' function, whereby if the user ticks the remember me box on the login form then the maxAge of the iron-session cookie is set to a week rather than my default value of 24 hours.

However, I can't work out a way to set the value programatically. I've tried the following but I get 'rememberMe not defined' on the ternary.

```
export default withIronSessionApiRoute(
  async function loginRoute(req, res) {
    const { username, password, rememberMe } = req.body;
    await req.session.save();
    return res.status(200).send('Logged in');
  },
  {
    cookieName: 'DEMOAUTH',
    password: 'PmsDH2Hm09rP7XRJkuo7TKDQXtowtBjurW66RUzU',
    ttl: rememberMe ? 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 : 60 * 60 * 24,
  }
);
```

EDIT following Jesse's comment - I tweaked slightly, adding a const rememberMe = true to check the value was definitely being set and I get the same behaviour

```
export default withIronSessionApiRoute(
  async function loginRoute(req, res) {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    const rememberMe = true;
    await req.session.save();
    return res.status(200).send('Logged in');
  },
  {
    cookieName: 'DEMOAUTH',
    password: 'PmsDH2Hm09rP7XRJkuo7TKDQXtowtBjurW66RUzU',
    ttl: rememberMe ? 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 : 60 * 60 * 24,
  }
);
```

Comment: If it's not defined then it's not being sent in the request body, meaning it's something on the front-end. Start by making sure the checkbox name is the same as your variable name  and that it's included in the form.

Comment: I'm sending test requests from postman so I know the value is being provided in the request body. I feel like it's something to do with the fact that the cookie options object is declared outside of the loginRoute handler function which has access to the req/res objects but I can't work out a way around it

Answer (score 0):

*rememberMe* is defined outside of the scope in which you are trying to use it. That's why it's not defined.

As far as I know, it's not possible to change the iron-session configuration based on the request body as of now, but [here is an issue requesting that feature](https://github.com/vvo/iron-session/issues/410).

Maybe for this specific case what you can do is create two API endpoints with different cookie configurations.